# How do I pass a string to an click event in ASP.Net on a LinkButton click? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a string in my main body that takes from an array. I want to pass that to the click event on a linkbutton. Is there any way to do this? Any help much appreciated.
Example code below:

(main body)

```
string myLabelsName = column.ToString();

LinkButton myButton = new LinkButton();
myButton.Text = ("THIS IS MY BUTTON");
myButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(myButton_Click);
```

(event)

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        I WANT THE STRING 'myLabelsName' Here <<
        Response.Redirect(myLabelsName + ".aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use fields/properties or more appropriate here: the LinkButton's [`CommandName` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
string myLabelsName = column.ToString();
LinkButton myButton = new LinkButton();
myButton.Text = "THIS IS MY BUTTON";
myButton.CommandName = myLabelsName;
myButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(myButton_Click);

// ...

protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btn = (LinkButton) sender;
    string myLabelsName = btn.CommandName;
    Response.Redirect(myLabelsName + ".aspx");
}
```

By the way, you're using a `LinkButton`, why don't you use it's [`PostBackUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx) property directly?

Comment: @user3809554: no, why do you want that?